# (android) set homescreen wallpaper with the correct dimensions

Tags: android, dimensions, wallpaper, homescreen

i'm currently building an app and i want to change the wallpaper. So here is my code.
When the user sets the wallpaper i save the path to Shared Preferences.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

SharedPreferences prefs = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
if (prefs.contains(d)) {
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(prefs.getString(d, ""));

    int newWidth = display.getWidth();
    int newHeight = display.getHeight();

    Bitmap resizedBitmap =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg, newWidth, newHeight, true);
    myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(resizedBitmap);
}
```

and with that code i got something like [this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/12/image1er.jpg/) while i want to show the pictures like [this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/image3bp.jpg/)

any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found out how to do this.
First i create a new bitmap

```
newBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(display.getWidth(), display.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

then the original bitmap resized:

```
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg, scaleWidth, scaleHeight, false);
```

then i call overlay to draw both images together. The first image has the dimensions of the display and the second is the image.

```
vate Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2, int left, int imgsize) {
   Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
   canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
   canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, left-(imgsize/2), 15, null);
   return bmOverlay;
}
```

and finally:

```
myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(newB);
```